# ORA12704 Error in Oracle Trigger

Tags: oracle10g

I have a trigger that is compiling okay but is throwing a ORA12704 character mismatch error.
This is the line that throws the error

```
Begin
   if :new.ADD_TEXT = '{8A9AFF65-9BD8-4B2A-8686-5279CC34F24B}' and
      :new.MORE_TEXT is null then
      :new.MORE_TEXT := substr(:new.RES_TXT, instr(:new.RES_TXT, '.',-1)+1, 10);
```

Comment: please post the DDL for the table, is one of the columns NVARCHAR2/NCLOB?

Comment: ADD_TEXT is VARCHAR2 38
MORE_Text is NVARCHAR2 500
RES_TXT is NVARCHAR2 500

Comment: does changing the instr to `instr(:new.RES_TXT, n'.',-1)+1, 10)` make any difference also what exact version of oracle as i cannot replicate the issue here. do you have a sample insert with values for those columns that causes the failure (with the trigger only containing the lines above)

Answer (score 0):

Try and change the line

```
  :new.MORE_TEXT := substr(:new.RES_TXT, instr(:new.RES_TXT, '.',-1)+1, 10);
```

to

```
  :new.MORE_TEXT := substr(:new.RES_TXT, instr(:new.RES_TXT, n'.',-1)+1, 10);
```

i.e. have the 1st and second parameters in the instr function call matched in datatype. I am unable to replicate the issue on 10.2.0.4 even with having that parameter as `'.'` though.

.e.g if you run this boiled testcase on your machine with your insert value, does it fail?

```
drop table tester;
create table tester
(
ADD_TEXT  VARCHAR2 (38),
MORE_Text NVARCHAR2(500),
RES_TXT  NVARCHAR2(500)
);

create trigger tester_trig
before insert on tester
for each row
declare
begin
   if :new.ADD_TEXT = '{8A9AFF65-9BD8-4B2A-8686-5279CC34F24B}' and
      :new.MORE_TEXT is null then
      :new.MORE_TEXT := substr(:new.RES_TXT, instr(:new.RES_TXT, '.',-1)+1, 10); 
  end if;

end;
/

insert into tester values ('{8A9AFF65-9BD8-4B2A-8686-5279CC34F24B}', '', 'your.value' );
select * from tester;
```

EDIT:

as per your new trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger_001
  2  Before Insert or update ON tester
  3  for each row
  4  declare
  5    v1_ext varchar2(10);
  6  Begin
  7    if :new.ADD_TEXT = '{8A9AFF65-9BD8-4B2A-8686-5279CC34F24B}'
  8      and :new.MORE_TEXT is null
  9    then
 10      :new.MORE_TEXT := substr(:new.RES_TXT, instr(:new.RES_TXT, '.',-1)+1, 10);
 11      select Case :new.MORE_TEXT
 12        WHEN 'avi' THEN 'video/x-msvideo'
 13        WHEN 'doc' THEN 'application/msword'
 14        else 'application/unknown'
 15      end
 16      into :new.MORE_TEXT
 17      from dual;
 18    end if;
 19    v1_ext := null;
 20  END;
 21  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for TRIGGER TEST_TRIGGER_001:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
8/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/12     PL/SQL: ORA-12704: character set mismatch
```

fix with `n`

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger_001
  2  Before Insert or update ON tester
  3  for each row
  4  declare
  5    v1_ext varchar2(10);
  6  Begin
  7    if :new.ADD_TEXT = '{8A9AFF65-9BD8-4B2A-8686-5279CC34F24B}'
  8      and :new.MORE_TEXT is null
  9    then
 10      :new.MORE_TEXT := substr(:new.RES_TXT, instr(:new.RES_TXT, n'.',-1)+1, 10);
 11      select Case :new.MORE_TEXT
 12        WHEN n'avi' THEN n'video/x-msvideo'
 13        WHEN n'doc' THEN n'application/msword'
 14        else n'application/unknown'
 15      end
 16      into :new.MORE_TEXT
 17      from dual;
 18    end if;
 19    v1_ext := null;
 20  END;
 21  /

Trigger created.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL> insert into tester values ('{8A9AFF65-9BD8-4B2A-8686-5279CC34F24B}', '', 'foo.avi');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from tester;

ADD_TEXT
--------------------------------------
MORE_TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RES_TXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{8A9AFF65-9BD8-4B2A-8686-5279CC34F24B}
video/x-msvideo
foo.avi
```

Comment: That worked, what next.
<code>
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger_001
   Before Insert or update
   ON tester for each row
declare
   v1_ext varchar2(10);
Begin
   if :new.ADD_TEXT = '{8A9AFF65-9BD8-4B2A-8686-5279CC34F24B}' and
      :new.MORE_TEXT is null then
      :new.MORE_TEXT := substr(:new.RES_TXT, instr(:new.RES_TXT, '.',-1)+1, 10);
select
         Case :new.MORE_TEXT
           WHEN 'avi' THEN 'video/x-msvideo'
           WHEN 'doc' THEN 'application/msword'
    else 'application/unknown'
         end
into :new.MORE_TEXT from dual;
   end if;
   v1_ext := null;
END;
</code>

Comment: @user1655869 you see you're mixing NVARCHAR and varchar literals. so do the same fix here `:new.MORE_TEXT WHEN 'avi'` should be `:new.MORE_TEXT WHEN n'avi'` same with `doc` , `application/msword` and `'application/unknown'` should all have the `n` operator on them!